# Apache Camel - protocol buffer endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, netty, protocol-buffers

I am trying to create a camel endpoint that listens on a tcp port to receive a message encoded using protocol buffers. [https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/]

I am trying to use netty to open the tcp port but I cannot get it to work.

My camel route builder is:

```
    from("netty:tcp://localhost:9000?sync=false").to("direct:start");
    from("direct:start").unmarshal(format)
                        .to("log:protocolbuffers?level=DEBUG")
                        .to("mock:result");
```

I have tried the `textline` code, but this just causes the error `com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.`

I think I need to use a byte array codec rather than a String, but I can't see a way to do it. I think I could write a custom endpoint to do it, but I'd rather not. Any  pointers would be much appreciated.

I sent the message to the camel endpoint using the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TestProtos.Person me = TestProtos.Person.newBuilder().setId(2).setName("Alan").build();
            //set up socket
            SocketChannel serverSocket;
            serverSocket = SocketChannel.open();
            serverSocket.socket()
                        .setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9000));
            serverSocket.configureBlocking(true);

            //create BAOS for protobuf
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            //mClientDetails is a protobuf message object, dump it to the BAOS
            me.writeDelimitedTo(baos);

            //copy the message to a bytebuffer
            ByteBuffer socketBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray());

            //keep sending until the buffer is empty
            while (socketBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                serverSocket.write(socketBuffer);
            }
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error....");
        }
    }
}
```

I also ran a test using a file endpoint which worked as expected. I created the file 
with:

```
@Test
public void fileTest() throws Exception {
    TestProtos.Person me = TestProtos.Person.newBuilder().setId(2).setName("Chris").build();

    File file = new File("/tmp/test.txt");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    me.writeTo(out);

    out.close();
};
```

Comment: How large is the serialized info being sent?

Comment: Tiny, my test "message" is 9 bytes.

Comment: @AndrewBraithwaite Did you find the solution?

Comment: @lobo I'm afraid not.